# UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:... Off-Center

Tags: ios, uikit, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm presenting a popover from a bar button item, and the arrow of the popover is not centred horizontally beneath the item:

[image: presenting popover from bar button item]

I'd like to budge that over to the left by a few pixels.

It doesn't occur on all `UIBarButtonItem` instances, just once I create with custom images. So for instance, the rightmost button item has a perfectly centred arrow and it's instantiated using a system  item:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(shareButtonWasPressed:)]
```

But if I use a custom image,

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:slideshowImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(slideshowButtonWasPressed:)]
```

... it's off-centre. I've tried adjusting the `imageInsets` of the button item, but it stretches the image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the easiest way to do this is implement your own subclass of `UIPopoverBackgroundView` and use it to adjust where it displays the arrow. This involves a lot of custom drawing code and I couldn't have done it without a designer, but we wanted a custom background anyway, so it was worth it.

Still no idea how I'd fix this without what's arguable a work around.